# how to use index match in from one file to another file in vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm new to VBA, just started learning couple of days ago.

I'm trying to convert this index/match function into Excel VBA

```
=INDEX('[039.xls]Sales Ledger Outstanding Invoic'!$D:$D,MATCH(D2,'[039.xls]Sales Ledger Outstanding Invoic'!$E:$E,0))
```

This is what I come up so far:

```
Dim E As Long, f As Long, g As Long
    Set tempWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\EDI\SLT report\039.xls", True, True).Worksheets("Sales Ledger Outstanding Invoic").Range("D2:D100")
    Set dataWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\EDI\SLT report\039.xls", True, True).Worksheets("Sales Ledger Outstanding Invoic").Range("E2:E100")
    E = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    g = 1
    For f = 2 To E
        If IsEmpty(Cells(f, "D")) = False Then
          Cells(f, "D") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(tempWB, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(A2, dataWB, 0))
            g = g + 1
        End If
    Next f
```

But this code giving me

> Subscript out of range

Can someone help me to solve it. Thanks

Comment: What line throws the error?  Note there's no `e` on `Invoic` in the Worksheet name...

Comment: @BruceWayne : This line 'Cells(f, "D") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(tempWB, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(A2, dataWB, 0))'. And nothing to do with the 'e' in the name

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting doesn't seem to relate to this line of code, but you might give this a try:

```
Cells(f, "D") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(tempWB, Application.Match(Range("A2"), dataWB, 0))
```

Comment: Good catch, also OP will probably want/need to qualify the range with what workbook and worksheet it's on.

Comment: Make sure that you're using Application.Match and NOT Application.WorksheetFunction.Match. For some odd reason, that does not work properly.

Comment: @tlemaster now I'm getting **Subscript out of range error** on following this line: 'Set tempWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\EDI\SLT report\039.xls", True, True).Worksheets("Sales Ledger Outstanding Invoic").Range("D2:D100")'